# Volume of the unit ball through areas of spheres

Tags: integration, geometry, analysis

How can the following formula be proved?

$$
|B_n| = \int_0^1 r^{n-1} \sigma_n \, dr = \frac{\sigma_n}{n}.
$$

Here, $|B_n|$ is volume of the unit ball in $\mathbb R^n$ and $\sigma_n$ is area of the unit sphere in $\mathbb R^n$.

The expression under the integral represents area of the sphere with radius $r$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply the divergence theorem on the unit ball with the identity vector field. The integral on the sphere will be the integral of the constant function $1$, and the integral in the ball will be the integral of the divergence of such field, namely the constant function $n$.

Explicitly, let $V:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be given by $V(x)=x$. Then $\mathrm{div}V=n$. Since the outer normal vector field $\eta$ on the unit sphere coincides with the restriction of $V$, we have that $\langle V , \eta \rangle=\langle \eta, \eta \rangle=1$ . It follows that
$$\int_B n= \int_S 1 $$
$$ \implies n\mathrm{vol}(B)=\mathrm{vol}(S).$$

Answer (score 3):

The surface area of any $n$ dimensional sphere is proportional to $r^{n-1}$. You can get this using the surface element $ds=r^{n-1}d\Omega_n$, where $\Omega_n$ is the $n$-dimensional solid angle.  Let's say the constant of proportionality is $C_n$. You can consider the sphere made out of infinitesimal spherical shells of thickness $dr$, so $$|B_n|=\int_0^1C_nr^{n-1}dr=C_n\frac{r^{n}}{n}\Bigg|_0^1=\frac{C_n}{n}=\frac{\sigma_n}{n}$$

Comment: How do you prove that $C_n = \sigma_n$?
The crucial moment in the statement is that $|B_n| = \int_0^1 r^{n-1} \sigma_n \, dr$. I can't prove this rigorously.

Comment: $\sigma_n=C_n r^{n-1}|_{r=1}$

Comment: How can it be proved rigorously? Why can we consider the sphere made out of infinitesimal spherical shells of thickness $dr$?

Comment: Because you can subdivide the interval $[0,1]$ in a set of infinitesimally small intervals. You have the definition of the "filled" sphere of radius $r$ as all the points in $\mathbb R^n$ at a distance less or equal to $r$ from the origin. You can then create a sphere with radius $r+dr$. The difference between the two is by definition a spherical shell

Comment: Thanks, but I don't see a rigorous proof that $C_n = \sigma_n$.

Comment: On the surface of the sphere, we take a surface element $ds$. When integrated over the whole surface you get the surface of the sphere. We can write $ds$ in terms of the $n$-dimensional solid angle and the radius. By definition, $d\Omega_n=\frac{ds}{r^{n-1}}$. So $\int_S ds=r^{n-1}\int_S d\Omega_n=r^{n-1}C_n$. For a sphere of radius $1$, we denote the surface area as $\sigma_n$, which by the above formula is $C_n$. I am not sure why you don't think that's enough proof.

Comment: Yes, but how to prove that $|B_n| = \int_0^1 C_n r^{n-1}\,dr$ ?
Where the formula for a repeated integral come from?
$\int_{B_n} = \int_0^1 \int_{S_r} \,d\Omega_n dr$